# I would like someone to translate the writing on this plate in to english please

Tags: translation

I would like someone to translate the writing on this plate in to english please [image]

Comment: very strange writing. mix of classical and modern writings. since the rule says: {Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service." I am not going to translate it for you, however, I can put them in order and you can go from there.

Comment: I have been trying to translate it for over a month now and haven't got anywhere, I have only just started learning chinese and do not understand any off this text. that is why i'm asking if anywould would be so kind to translate it for me. :)

Comment: If i had the translation i would be able to start to despyphere it and start understand how it is layed out and written for the next plate i have

Comment: The original poem, 尋故人 written by 元代 黃清老 is: 
適興一尋君，君家在白雲。幽花秋後見，落葉夜深聞。
隨意坐苔石，呼童煮澗芹。不須談世事，詩思正紛紛。
There are three different words.
適興一尋君，君家在白雲。幽花秋後見，落葉夜深聞。
隨**喜**坐**台**石，呼童煮澗芹。不須談世事，詩**意**正紛紛。
The other one is: 
言易招尤，對朋友少說幾句。
書能益智，勸兒孫多讀數行。
(I only show the Chinese words here so that other users can use it. I have no time to translate it.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the rule here, I cannot translate the text for you as it is.

Here is the sorted out version. You can use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.ca/) to try to translate it. You can go line by line first. If the outcome seems wrong, then refine your search and look at individual words that do not seem right.

After you get the rough translation that somewhat makes sense, but not completely, then you can ask specific questions on items that are difficult to understand.

> *The original poem, 尋故人 written by 元代 黃清老 is: 適興一尋君，君家在白雲。幽花秋後見，落葉夜深聞。 隨意坐苔石，呼童煮澗芹。不須談世事，詩思正紛紛。 There are three different words. 適興一尋君，君家在白雲。幽花秋後見，落葉夜深聞。 隨喜坐台石，呼童煮澗芹。不須談世事，詩意正紛紛。 The other one is: 言易招尤，對朋友少說幾句。 書能益智，勸兒孫多讀數行。 (I only show the Chinese words here so that other users can use it. I have no time to translate it.) –* [user-487](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/15652/user-487)

適興一尋君, 君家在白雲.

幽花秋後見, 落葉夜深聞.

隨意坐苔石, 呼童煮澗芹.

不須談世事, 詩意正紛紛.

~~

言易招尤, 對朋友少說幾句.

書能益智, 勸兒孫多讀幾行.

Edit:

Since you write that many comments and consider Google Translate is not very good at translating text written in classical style, I would give you the rough meaning of this text.

適興一尋君 (I have a sudden urge to seek you), 君家在白雲 (your home is in the cloud). *somewhere remote*

幽花秋後見 (Pale flowers are seen after fall arrived, ), 落葉夜深聞 (Falling leaves are heard at late night).

隨意坐苔石(Sit on the mossed rock at will), 呼童煮澗芹 (call the kid to cook some Jian qin). *a kind of vegetable*

不須談世事 (No need to talk about the world's affair"  , 詩意正紛紛 (One after another, the poetry feelings is coming).

~~

言易招尤 (Spoken words easily cause trouble) , 對朋友少說幾句(speak a few words less to friends).

書能益智 (Books can benefit minds), 勸兒孫多讀幾行 (advise your children and grandchildren to read a few lines more).

Comment: Hi And thank you for that i am new to all this computer stuff ive tried the translator and it dosent work guess i will just leave it fed up now ith trying to translate it but thank you anyway

Comment: Fine, I edited the answer. Now you know what is in the text